# I Didn't Get Whats wrong with this exemple Assembly

Tags: assembly, scroll, x86-16, bmp

i made a simple exemple of scrolling bmp
and i didnt understand Two things:

1.why the image start from the middle

2.why after the x change on the screen there is a line in the middle

i really need help
besause i on it a week and i cant solve it

the code:

```
        IDEAL

        MODEL large
    Macro ReadBmp FileName
        mov [Lines],0
        mov [Weight],0



        mov ax,[Y]
        mov [CurrentY],ax

        mov [XScreen],0
        mov [YScreen],0


        mov dx, offset FileName  ;Mov Dx Offset Of File To Read It
        ;call ClearBuff
        call ReadToBuffer       ;Call Proc That Move Values To Buffer
        call ShowBMP

        mov ax,[CurrentY]
        mov [Y],ax
    EndM
    P386
        STACK 256

        RightDown        equ 77
        LeftDown         equ 75
        UpDown           equ 72
        DownDown         equ 80
        ScreenRam        equ 0A000h

        DATASEG
        ErrorMsg         DB 'There Is A Problem To Show The File$'
        Handle           DW ?
        File             DB 'Map.bmp',0
        Index            DD ?
        X                DW 0
        Y                DW 0
        CurrentY         DW 0
        XScreen          DW 0
        YScreen          DW 0
        Weight           DW 0
        Lines            DB 0
        ;SizeFile DD 0 
    SEGMENT BufferBmp para public  ;'DATA'  
            DB 65535 DUP(0)
    ENDS

            CODESEG   

    Start:
            mov ax, @data
            mov ds, ax

            mov ax, BufferBmp
            mov es, ax

            mov ax, 0013h
            int 10h

    Draw:           
            ReadBmp File
    lop:        

            mov ah,00
            int 16h
            cmp ah,RightDown
            je Right
            cmp ah,LeftDown
            je Left
            cmp ah,UpDown
            je Up
            cmp ah,DownDown
            je Down
            cmp ah,1
            je Exit
    jmp lop

    Right:
        add [X],5
    jmp Draw
    Left:
        sub [X],5
    jmp Draw
    Up:
        sub [Y],5
    jmp Draw
    Down:
        add [Y],5
    jmp Draw

    Exit:
            mov ax,04c00h
            int 21h

    Proc ClearBuff near
        mov si,0
        mov al,15
    NoFinish:
        mov [es:si],al
        inc si
        cmp si,65535
        jne NoFinish
    ;-----------------------------Clear Screen-----------------------------;
            mov ax,ScreenRam      
            xor di,di                           
            mov cx,320*200/2                    
            mov al,0d                           
            mov ah,0d                           
            rep stosw                           
    ;-----------------------------Clear Screen-----------------------------;
        ret
    endp
    Proc ReadToBuffer near
    ;--------------------OpenFile Use Handle--------------------;
        mov ah, 3Dh             ;INT 21 Know If Ah == 3dh He Need To Open/Create File
        mov al, 0               ;Read Only
        ;mov dx,offset FileName
        int 21h
        jc  @@Err
        mov [Handle], ax        ;Handle On ax Go To Var
    ;--------------------Copy Lines To Buffer------------------;
    ;--------------------Move Pointer To Check End Of File--------------------;
    ;   mov     ah,  42h                 ;int 21h Know That If AH == 42h He Move Pointer On File
    ;   mov     al,  02                  ;End Of File To Know Size Of A File
    ;   mov     bx, [Handle]             ;BX = file handle
    ;   xor     ecx,ecx                  ;CX:DX = offset from origin of new file position.
    ;   xor     edx,edx                  ;CX:DX = offset from origin of new file position.  
    ;   int     21h                 
    ;   jc      @@Err
    ;   ;Enter The Image Size Into A Variable
    ;   mov     [SizeFile],eax 
    ;   mov     eax,65536
    ;   mul     edx
    ;   add     [SizeFile],eax
    ;   cmp     [SizeFile],0
    ;   je     @@Err
    ;--------------------Move Pointer To Check End Of File--------------------;
    @@Lop:         
    ;--------------------Calculate index By WY+X-------------;
        mov     eax, 1920                ;Eax == 1920(Weight Of Map)
        xor     ebx, ebx                 ;ebx = 0
        mov     bx,  [Y]                 ;Bx == Y   
        mul     ebx                      ;W*Y
        xor     ebx, ebx                 ;Ebx = 0
        add     ax, [X]                  ;WY+X 
    ;--------------------Calculate index By WY+X-------------;
    ;--------------------Flip Image--------------------;
        ;mov    [index],eax              ;index == eax
        ;mov     eax,[SizeFile]          ;eax == All Byte Image 
        ;sub     eax,[index]                 ;Eax - Index
    ;--------------------Flip Image--------------------;

        mov     [index],eax              ;index == eax
        xor     edx, edx                 ;edx = 0
        mov     ebx, 65536               ;ebx = 65536
        div     ebx                      ;Dx = Remains,ax = dose
        mov     ecx,  eax                ;CX = high order word of number of bytes to move
        xor     ebx, ebx                 ;edx = 0
                                        ;CX:DX distance to move file pointer: offset is (CX * 65536) + DX

    ;--------------------Move Pointer To Read Data--------------------;
        mov     ah,  42h                 ;int 21h Know That If AH == 42h He Move Pointer On File
        mov     al,  00                  ;Current Location Plus Offset
        mov     bx, [Handle]             ;BX = file handle
                                        ;CX:DX = offset from origin of new file position. 
        int     21h                 
        jc      @@Err
    ;--------------------Move Pointer To Read Data--------------------;

    ;--------------------Read Data--------------------;

        mov     bx, [Handle]             ;BX = file handle
        mov     dx, [Weight]             ;DS:DX = pointer to read buffer
        pusha     
        push    ds
        mov     ax, BufferBmp
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     cx, 320                 ;CX = number of bytes to read---;320 = Line;
        mov     ah, 3Fh
        int     21H
        pop     ds
        popa
        jc      @@Err           
    ;--------------------Read Data--------------------;
        inc     [Lines]
        inc     [Y]                      ;Add Y To Calculate Position
        add     [Weight], 320            ;Add Weight X
        cmp     [Lines],  200            ;Check End
        jne     @@Lop

        mov     ah, 3Eh                  ;Close File
        mov     bx,[Handle]              ;BX = file handle
        int     21H
        jc      @@Err   
        ret

    @@Err:  
            mov     ax, 3                ; Set text mode
            int     10h
            mov     dx, offset ErrorMsg
            mov     ah, 09h
            int     21h                  ;Print Error
            jmp     Exit
    endp

    Proc ShowBMP near
        mov si,0                     ;Start From The Begining Of Buffer
        mov bx,0                         ;page 0
    @@Horizontal:                        
        mov ah,0Ch                       ;int 10h Know That If AH == 0Ch He Write Graphics Pixel at Coordinate
        mov al, [es:si]                  ;Color
        mov cx,[XScreen]                 ;X
        mov dx,[YScreen]                 ;Y
        int 10h
        inc si                           ;mov to next pixel
        inc [XScreen]                    ;Add X
        cmp [XScreen],320                ;Check End Line
        jne @@Horizontal
        inc [YScreen]                    ;Add Y
        mov [XScreen],0                  ;Start New Line
        cmp [YScreen],200                ;Check End Of Image
        jne @@Horizontal
    ret
    endp



    End Start
```

The program using this image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8aBZr8mtCUmQL2WKmQfklmEMfaOCklG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your ShowBMP code seems to assume that the image is 320x200, but the file I downloaded from that link is 1920x600?  BMPs store their dimensions in the file.  Why not read it?  Then you could count down from there and exit when you hit zero.

Comment: I would like to help you on this one but didn't you like my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410379/dont-understand-whats-wrong-with-my-pcx-code) about PCX?

Comment: Oh i Didnt see the comment...

Comment: Anyway how do I solve my problems? :)

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: @David Wohlferd Your advide is related to the problems?
How Can i Read the dimensions?

Comment: @SepRoland 
Thank you very much 
You really help me :)

It's good to meet nice people

Comment: The dimensions are stored in the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29) that Sep mentions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add ax, [X]

When calculating the file offset you forget to consider the carry from adding *X*

```
mov     eax, 1920                ;Eax == 1920(Weight Of Map)
xor     ebx, ebx                 ;ebx = 0
mov     bx,  [Y]                 ;Bx == Y   
mul     ebx                      ;W*Y
xor     ebx, ebx                 ;Ebx = 0
mov     bx, [X]  
add     eax, ebx   <<<< correct addition
```

The conversion of this 32-bit number into CX:DX is simply:

```
push eax
pop  dx
pop  cx
```

That division by 65536 was not useful.
Now you can call DOS.function 42h.

---

Every .BMP graphics file starts with a header that contains important information about the picture. For your 256-color bitmap file these are:

- a 14 byte BITMAPFILEHEADER
- a 40 byte BITMAPINFOHEADER
- a 1024 byte COLORTABLE

Then come the pixel data that you need. That's why your calculation of the file offset should **add eax, 14+40+1024**.

```
movzx   eax, word [Y]       ; Y position within bitmap
imul    eax, 1920           ; Width of bitmap
movzx   ebx, word [X]       ; X position within bitmap
lea     eax, [eax+ebx+1078] <<<< Plus offset to start of pixel data
push    eax
pop     dx
pop     cx
```

Comment: you are really genius
but still its starting from the middle of the image when the x,y = 0,
why?

still i didnt get why to x there is a carry


the biggest x is 320

Comment: @Gad A carry from `add ax, [X]` does not only depend on the value in *X*. What's in `AX` made the addition overflow!

Comment: @Gad Thank you so much. I just love that little heart.